# Ubuntu installer does not see windows 8 after changing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi, system-installation

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu (and Windows 8 for that matter).  Here is my story so far in case these details matter.  I have a brand new windows 8 machine, and I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8.

I have a CD for Ubuntu 12.04.4 32bit.  I read that I needed to turn off Secure Boot and change my the setting in my bios form UEFI to legacy.

This allowed me to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 32bit, and I did so using the normal install (not making the partitions manually).  Ubuntu worked fine, but when I selected Windows 8 from the startup menu I got a Windows Boot Manager error saying something had changed and I need to repair the boot for windows.  I switched back to UEFI and Windows booted fine, but of course, I get no Ubuntu.

Since then I have come to learn my error was installing a 32bit version under legacy instead of a 64bit version under UEFI.  So I got the latest version of Ubuntu (14.04) and put it on a bootable USB.  I also read that it was best to do the partitioning under windows so it essentially understands what is happening.  So I deleted the Ubuntu partition, the swap partition, and the 1mb grub partition, all of which I assumed were put there by Ubuntu.  I then created two new unformatted partitions which will eventually be used for Ubuntu and the swap partition.  I assumed the installer could handle creating another grub partition (maybe this is where my mistake is).

So here is where my problem comes in:  Now I have swiched Secure boot and UEFI back on and booted from my USB with Ubuntu 14.04.  When I get to the part where it asks me what type of install I want to do, it says no operating system found, and my only real option is to format and just run Ubuntu.  Yet, when I take my USB out Windows boots without any problem.

So my question is, why is Ubuntu not recognizing that Windows 8 exists.  I know the old version did in legacy mode, and I think the new one did also before I changed the partitions.  Did this happen because I deleted the grub partition?

Comment: From the Ubuntu LiveUSB, can you provide the output of `gdisk -l`? I have a sneaking suspicion you may have deleted your ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide the output of gdisk.  I can look it up here in a minute.  However, when I go into the disk manegment in windows I clearly see a 260mb partition named "EFI system partition"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are doing the "do something else" when asked to where to install the OS, not alongside windows, not by itself, do "do something else" choose a partition for ubuntu make it / so it knows where the root is. if you have more than 3-4 gb ram I dont even recommend swap, just waste of space, its for older computers and assuming your pc is win8 then it has to be new. at the same place where you choose partition for the OS, choose a device you put bootloader on and thats it, I always do it that way on any computer with any OS combination and never had a problem, hope it helps!

Comment: of course prepare the empty partition with no formatting from windows, you cant modify windows partition from the installation menu

Comment: If I simply make a new partition and install Ubuntu will it bring up Win 8 as a boot option on the grub menu if it doesn't see it there in the first place?

Comment: yes it will I assume as long as you put bootloader on the same device as win8 and ubuntu will be on

Comment: I created partitions in Windows 8 without formatting them.  Then in the Ubuntu installer I used the "do something else" option and formatted those partitions I created in Windows and then continued to install Ubuntu.  Despite the fact that the Ubuntu installer did not see Windows on the computer, it still listed it in grub.  The install went great, and now Ubuntu and Windows 8 are both working.  Thanks!